# Bash Script: Error when using variable in curl data

Tags: bash, curl

I've been working on creating a script utilizes curl and variables. Doing some searches I found how to place a variable in the data portion of the curl but now I'm getting errors from the curl command.

(Some parts of the code removed to keep passwords out, everything is working except for entering the data into the --data portion of curl)

```
curlData=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "rebootClient": false,
    "createPseudoClientRequest": {
        "registerClient": true,
        "clientInfo": {
            "clientType": 0,
        }
    },
    "packages": [
        {
            "packageId": 702,
            "packageName": "File System",
            "packageId": 51,
            "packageName": "MediaAgent"
        }
    ],

    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "clientId": 0,

        }
    ]
}
EOF
)

shopt -u nocasematch #Sets options back to being case sensitive

echo "$csName"

curl -vv --location --request POST "http://$csName:81/SearchSvc/CVWebService.svc/InstallClient" --header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header "Authtoken: $token" \
 -d "$curlData"
```

Doing a bash -x everything looks correct

```
    "rebootClient": false,
    "createPseudoClientRequest": {
        "registerClient": true,
        "clientInfo": {
            "clientType": 0,
        }
    },
    "packages": [
        {
            "packageId": 702,
            "packageName": "File System",
                        "packageId": 51,
                        "packageName": "MediaAgent"
        }
    ],
    "clientAuthForJob": {
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "clientId": 0,
            "clientName": "srybrcost",
        }
    ]
}'
```

But every time I get Request body is empty or format is invalid

Comment: You could share the actual call to `curl`, so it's easier to spot the issue.

Comment: Use jq for check you json format.

Comment: I'm no JSON expert but at a first glance it looks like you've got a couple of extra commas there. Specifically after "clientType": 0, and "clientName": "srybrcost", - there should be no comma at the end of these 2 lines.